# Is there a way to tell if ReactElement renders "null"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my JSX, I have a case of a conditional rendering logic - when element A renders something (it's `render()` function returns something other than `null`), then also render element B, just above the element A.

Code example (simplified) would look like this:

```
function render() {
    let elemA = (<ElementA someProp={this.someVar} />);

    if (elemA.isNull()) {
        return (
            <div>
                { ...someElements }
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            { ...someElements }
            <ElementB />
            { elemA }
        </div>
    );
}
```

**So my question is** - Is there any way to have the `elemA.isNull()` check?

Comment: React might not "know" if elemA has rendered anything at this point, since the render method just describes a structure.

Comment: Ok, so in that case, I see two options to solve this:  
**a)** Create a custom method inside ElementA class, which would tell me whether it will render ``null`` or something else
**b)** Move the conditional rendering inside ElementA, and pass anything to render as a prop.

| I'm not sure if the former option is actually possible, though...

Comment: If ElementA is a pure component (onky describe by props), then it should also be possible to tell from this.someVar whether ElementA would be rendered.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, there's no way to determine what a child will render using React. The standard way to do this is to expose some utility function that says whether A will render.

Something like:

```
if (AUtils.isStoryValid(story)) {
  return <A story={story} />;
} else {
  return <B story={story} />;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that if your ReactElement has been written as a functional component you can call the function like any other and check its response.
As a simple example, I have a function component that returns different icons based on a prop being passed in:

```
import React from "react";

import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
import GroupIcon from "@material-ui/icons/People";

export default function EntityIcon({ entity }) {
  switch (entity) {
    case "people":
      return <PersonIcon />;
    case "groups":
      return <GroupIcon />;
    default:
      console.error(`entity: ${entity} doesn't have an associated icon`);
      return null;
  }
}
```

The above is usually referenced with:

```
    <ListItemIcon>
      <EntityIcon entity={search.entity} />
    </ListItemIcon>
```

But I can do some conditional magic if needed with:

```
  if (EntityIcon({ entity: item.entity })) {
    ... conditional magic
  }
```

`search.entity` and `item.entity` happen to be properties of an array of objects in my use-case, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Does this actually work? The boolean evaluation of a component that rendered null is true (at least in react 16.13), so your conditional will always trigger, regardless of what is rendered, won't it?

Comment: The code isn't actually rendering a component in the second case above. The `EntityIcon` function  either works as a React functional component or as a bog-standard javascript function based on the context under which it is run.

Comment: That won't work if you render a component with JSX tags (e.g. `<EntityIcon .../>`), in that case it'd always return some kind of object with cryptic stuff in it like `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)` etc. But it would work if you render it as a function: `EntityIcon(props)`

Comment: @DmitriPisarev - it works for me, so are you facing an issue? In JSX, my expectation is a React element, and in vanilla JS it returns an object or null

Comment: It's surprising how many people say something doesn't work without trying it first!

Comment: For future readers, I believe this won't work if `EntityIcon` uses a hook because hooks can only exist in a rendered React component.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following higher order component (HOC) to intercept the render method of ElementA and accomplish what you want:

```
function withNullCheck(WrappedComponent) {
  return class NullChecker extends WrappedComponent {
    render() {
      const result = super.render();
      return(
        <div>
          { this.props.alwaysPrefix }
          { result && this.props.ifNotNullPrefix }
          { result ? result : this.props.ifNull }
          { result && this.props.ifNotNullAppend }
          { this.props.alwaysAppend }
        </div>  
      );
    }
  }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
const NullCheckedElementA = withNullCheck(ElementA);

...

function render() {

    return ( 
      <NullCheckedElementA 
         alwaysPrefix={someElements} 
         ifNotNullPrefix={elemB} 
         someProp={this.someVar} 
      />
    );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

So I ran into a situation where I was stuck having to do this, here is a way that works (though the hackiness might make you cry).

Should only be used as a last resort because it really is a total hack and you'll take a ~0-20ms performance hit depending on component complexity.
(Provider is there assuming you're using redux and your component depends on your redux state):

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'pathToYourReduxStoreInstance';


export default function isRenderingNull(componentInstance) {
  return !renderToStaticMarkup(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {componentInstance}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: If performance is not a criteria, it's the most minimalistic way to do it. Why performance? You will probably render the content of the checked component twice and you will add an additional download overhead downloading the server functions for rendering react into the client

Answer (score 3):

It will be easy if your `ElementA` is function component. In this case you could do smt like this:

```
    function render() {
    let ElemA = ElementA({ someProp:  this.someVar});

    if (ElemA === null) {
        return (
            <div>
                { ...someElements }
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            { ...someElements }
            <ElementB />
            <ElemA />
        </div>
    );
}
```